# SQL change color of duplicated record

Tags: colors, duplicates, record

I've made an sign-up form for my sisters wedding. Now, when somebody have signed-up more than ones, it's kind of hard to notice. So i would like to highlight the  name on my result page when a name is signed up more than one time.

The result page is just a table with the name of the quest and the date he or she has signed-up.

Is there any way to do mark highlight those duplicate names? Something like this:

Chris
**Alex**
Tom
Pete
**Alex**
John

Comment: So this is not really anything to do with SQL is it? You're looking at post-processing your list of results, so you'll need to do this in JavaScript or PHP etc. Probably should change the tags.

Comment: this is obviously related to a user interface in an application and not to sql itself. Please edit your question to reflect the relevant tags (removing the irrelevant ones) and add the code where you're stuck so as to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)